# Extract pattern from multiple files and save with file names

Tags: count, grep

I can save the occurrence of the extracted pattern from multiple gzipped files in a single output file but I also want to save the input file name.

I have used grep command to extract patterns and wc -l to get a count of occurrences.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 for sample in *.gtf.gz;  
  do  
    #echo $sample   
   describer=$(echo ${sample} | sed 
 's/_sorted_astalavista.gtf.gz//')  
   echo $describer    

  zgrep -w '0,1-2^' $sample | wc -l | tee -a output2.txt
 done
```

For example, the occurrence of pattern in input_file_1 is 300 and its occurrence in input_file_2 is 500. I am able to save 300, 500 in a file:

300

500

but I also want to include input file names so that output looks like:

input_file_1 300

input_file_2 500

.

.

.

..

Comment: Add a pipe to `sed "s/^/$sample /"` after `wc -l` and before the pipe to `tee -a`.  That will add the filename to the beginning of each line.

Comment: also `describer=$(sed 's///' <<< $sample)` might be more readible than piping echo to sed.